# binding <p:datable> row with a form

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I click a row in `<p:dataTable>` and click a command button I want to show a new dialog and set the value of the row to a form(in new dialog). I use session bean to keep data of selected row but the data isn't changed when i select a new row. I think this is because of session bean which keeps data until the session expires. I've tried all scopes but no one worked

Here's my dataTable

```
<p:dataTable var="customer" 
        widgetVar="customerTable"
        value="#{customerFacade.findAll()}"
        selectionMode="single"
        rowKey="#{customer.customerid}"
        selection="#{editCustomerBean.customer}"
        paginator="true" rows="10"  
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">  
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{editCustomerBean.onRowSelect}" update=":form:growl"/>
```

Here's my command button and dialog

```
<h:form>
    <p:dialog id="edit" header="Edit Customer" widgetVar="editCustomerDlg" resizable="false" showEffect="fade">  
        <h:panelGrid id="editDisplay" columns="2" columnClasses="alignTop">                           
            <p:outputLabel for="editCompanyName" value="Company Name" />
            <p:inputText id="editCompanyName"label="Compnay Name" value="#{editCustomerBean.customer.companyname}" required="true" />
            <h:panelGroup/>
            <p:commandButton value="Edit Customer" update="editDisplay" oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed){editCustomerDlg.hide()}" actionListener="#{customerController.editCustomer}" />
        </h:panelGrid>  
    </p:dialog>
    <p:commandButton widgetVar="editBut" icon="ui-icon-tag" value="Edit"  oncomplete="editCustomerDlg.show()"/>  
</h:form>
```

here's my session bean

```
@Named(value = "editCustomerBean")
@SessionScoped
public class EditCustomerBean implements Serializable {
    private Customer customer;

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {  
        customer = (Customer) event.getObject();
        System.out.println(customer.getAddress());
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Customer Selected", ((Customer) event.getObject()).getPhone());  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    }

    public EditCustomerBean() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the problem now, that you dont get the right customer in onRowSelect or that there are the false values displayed in the dialog?

Comment: Yes, I don't get the right customer in the form. what's the problem?